# What's the error in my HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, regex, http-status-code-404, redirection

index page and profile page show 404 after htaccess redirection
I transfered from bogger to wp..

redirected all links from year/month/postname.html to postname/ using these lines:

```
# WPhtc: Begin Custom htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([^/]+).html$ /$3
```

then redirected all previous postname,html to postname/ using this line

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+).html$ /$1
```

I used these lines to redirect the mobile strings:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=[01]$
    RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

the final format is:

```
# WPhtc: Begin Custom htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=[01]$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([^/]+).html$ /$3
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+).html$ /$1
```

Then Ihave got, 404 error when opening pages like:
index.html
profile.php
etc

please help me identify the cause>

Comment: this question is way too complex to attract answer. Try to simplify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$
```

instead of

```
RewriteRule ^
```

For detailed explanation of rewrite flags i have shared the link below.

```
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html
```

Comment: Now I edited my HTACESS file as following:

Comment: I made changes..please see it above

Comment: What is the output now?

Comment: still have 404 for pages like index, profile, etc...

Comment: Is your home page started redirecting now? You are using  below listed flag conditions, which are possibly creating a flow.  (.*) /$1? Need to sort this out with correct combination of flags.